# PostGIS reports invalid Curve GML

Tags: postgis, gml

PostGIS version `POSTGIS="1.5.3" GEOS="3.3.1-CAPI-1.7.1" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009" LIBXML="2.7.3" USE_STATS`

Postgresql version `PostgreSQL 9.1.2`

I'm having issues inserting Curves into a PostGIS database using `st_geomfromgml()`.  Basically I'm hitting up Geoserver WFS services and storing returned geometries.

Here is an example of failing GML;

```
    <gml:Curve xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326" srsDimension="2">
      <gml:segments>
        <gml:LineStringSegment interpolation="linear">
          <gml:posList>-61.5681 -179.687 -61.52288589853826 -180.0</gml:posList>
        </gml:LineStringSegment>
        <gml:LineStringSegment interpolation="linear">
          <gml:posList>-61.52288589853826 -178.0 -61.5177 -179.9641</gml:posList>
        </gml:LineStringSegment>
      </gml:segments>
    </gml:Curve>
```

Yet if I split this up into multiple inserts like;

```
    <gml:Curve xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326" srsDimension="2">
      <gml:segments>
        <gml:LineStringSegment interpolation="linear">
          <gml:posList>-61.5681 -179.687 -61.52288589853826 -180.0</gml:posList>
        </gml:LineStringSegment>
      </gml:segments>
    </gml:Curve>

    <gml:Curve xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326" srsDimension="2">
      <gml:segments>
        <gml:LineStringSegment interpolation="linear">
          <gml:posList>-61.52288589853826 -178.0 -61.5177 -179.9641</gml:posList>
        </gml:LineStringSegment>
      </gml:segments>
    </gml:Curve>
```

It works fine.  What is incorrect with the original GML?